# If you delete a message sent on a WhatsApp group by some other user, do they or anyone else in the group know

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Suppose in a group some user sends a message and you accidentally or deliberately delete it, do the original poster gets some kind of notification that this other user deleted your message?

Comment: Simply No. What an user do on it's phone is not shown to other, except for when they're typing.

Comment: Whatsapp also shows when you have read the message. it also shows when you're online / last time you where online when you're one on one messaging.

Answer (score 1):

No the original poster doesn't gets any kind of notification.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is NO.

If you see the [info page](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567) of WhatsApp, there is no mention of other users noticing about the message delete by any user in a group. And this makes a perfect sense too because why anyone else need to know what I did with the message received. You may choose to `Favourite` a specific message and even that too is not informed to anyone else in the group including the original author of that group.

However, group wide changes such as 1.Group icon, 2. Group subject will be visible to all group members no matter who does it in a group.